# how to set spinner value to textView

Tags: android, buttonclick

i am new to programming please forgive for any blunder.
i am trying to assign a spinner value which is selected to TextView but every thing goes wrong.

OnCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.grades, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    grades=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    grades.setAdapter(adapter);
    grades.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity.this);
}
```

onSelectesItem Listner

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    TextView spinner_text=(TextView) view;
    Toast.makeText(this,"your grade is " + spinner_text.getText(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

   textView.setText(grades.getSelectedItem().toString());//this line should do its work but didnt goes well 
}
```

Comment: what exactly goes wrong? does it crash? or simply doesnt work

Comment: @MadScientist it just crashed

Comment: can you post the error log

Comment: @MadScientist there is no error while i build but when i run in emulator it just crashed by saying application can not start

Comment: Check the android monitor for the error logs. Possibly you might not have set the textview. call the findviewbyid on the text view to add a view to it.

Comment: @MadScientist Done but didnt works

Comment: it works fine when i just call it in toast but didnt work in textView

Comment: See my answer below. Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: where is the code to find the textview by id ??

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreate()` method, you did not get the reference of `TextView` using `findViewById(R.id.textView)` that's why in `onItemSelected()` when setting `text` to `textView` it causes application crash.

**Add below line in `onCreate()`**

```
textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.YOUR_TEXTVIEW_ID);
```

**Here is the full working code:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener {

    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    Spinner grades;
    TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        grades = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.grades, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

        grades.setAdapter(adapter);
        grades.setOnItemSelectedListener(MainActivity .this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        TextView spinner_text = (TextView) view;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Your grade is " + spinner_text.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        textView.setText(grades.getSelectedItem().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

    }
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected spinner values in following ways:

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String selectedString;
        //1: From the Adapter
        selectedString = adapter.getItem(position).toString();

        //2: From the spinner
        selectedString = grades.getSelectedItem().toString();

        //3: From the view 
        TextView spinner_text = (TextView) view;
        selectedString = spinner_text.getText().toString();

        //All of them works just fine choose any one method
        textView.setText(selectedString);
    }
```